# drag marker of OpenstreetMap not working

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

How can be  drag markar in openstreetMap using javascript
I have use below code which on not properly working , and how to Implement InfoWindow of a markar in opestreetMap using javascript

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers({
                    position: new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),
                    map: map,

                    draggable: true,
                    title: "static marker"
                });
```

Comment: Describe "not properly working".

Answer (score 0):

Create new Vector Layer :

```
 Layer.MARKER = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Marker Layers", { 
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': {
                externalGraphic: "${URL}",  
                graphicWidth:50,//pixel
                graphicHeight:50//pixel
            }
        }
            )
    });
```

Add Map:

```
map.addLayer(Layer.MARKER);
```

Drag Control Add

```
Control.DragText = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(Layer.MARKER); 
map.addControl(Control.DragText);
```

Activate control :

```
Control.DragText.activate();
//Deactive Control.DragText.deactivate();
```

finally add marker:

```
    var marker= new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat));
     marker.attributes = {
        URL: "marker_url"
};
Layer.MARKER.addFeatures([marker]);
```